# Thermal Energy, Heat and Friction using work-energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, work

The work-energy theory states:

> $\Delta$ K = W

John Taylor breaks work into conservative and non-conservative work:

> $\Delta K = W_c + W_{nc} $

One type of non-conservative work is friction, which i beak up into friction work and other non-conservative work

> $\Delta K = W_c + (W_{frict} + W_{nco}) $

According to the [Wikipedia article on friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction):

> $E_{th} = W_{frict} $

Hence,

> $\Delta K = W_c + (-E_{th} + W_{nco}) $

where the minus sign is due to the system doing the work on the surroundings. The potential energy is also found as:

> $\Delta K = - \Delta U + (-E_{th} + W_{nco}) $

Hence:

> $ E_{mech}  + E_{th} = W_{nco} $

In thermodynamics, we only care about

> $E_{th} = W_{nco}$

**The questions**:

- How do we get closer to the first law of thermodynamics: $ \Delta E_{int} = W + Q$?
- If $E_{th}$ is the temperature, then how does it fit into the first law?
- How does one obtain entropy from the work-energy

Comment: I have a draft of an answer but am hesitant to post it because in drafting it I kept encountering many statements needing clarification, from a thermodynamics standpoint. The following are a few.

Comment: 1. The first equation is incomplete. It should read: $\Delta K=W_{net}$. The work energy theorem states that the *net* work done on an object equals the change in its kinetic energy. The word "net" cannot be overemphasized here and it has a bearing on all the remaining equations where you use $\Delta K$ where instead of using $\Delta K$ you should simply be using $W$.

Comment: 2. The Wikipedia article equates friction work with heat. That is inaccurate. Friction raises the temperature of the surfaces do to work transfer, not heat transfer. The term “friction heating” is technically a misnomer since friction is not a heat transfer process.

Comment: 3. In one of your equations you use the symbol $U$ but do not define it. In thermodynamics $U$ stands for the internal energy of a closed system. Later you use $E_{int}$ as internal energy in connection with the first law.  Then what is $U$? I suspect you may mean it to be the total mechanical energy of a system, but that needs to be clarified.

Comment: 4. You say “in thermodynamics we only care about $T_{th}=W_{nco}$”. I don’t understand what that means. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding the **questions**:

> 1. How do we get closer to the first law of thermodynamics: $ \Delta
>    E_{int} = W + Q$?

Not by the series of equations given.

None of the preceding equations deals with heat, $Q$. Heat is energy transfer across the system boundary due to a temperature difference. The referenced Wikipedia article erroneously equated friction work, $W_{frict}$ with heat as they talked about "thermal energy" being synonymous with "heat" and as being equivalent to friction work. Friction work actually converts mechanical energy into internal energy, $E_{int}$, as reflected by a temperature increase due to the relative motion between the contacting surfaces. The temperature increase then can subsequently result in transfer of energy into the materials or into the environment in the form of heat.

> 2. If $E_{th}$ is the temperature, then how does it fit into the first
>      law?

Where did you previously refer to $E_{th}$ as being temperature? It was equated to friction work. Friction work is not temperature. Friction work done internal to the system can, however, increase the temperature and thus the internal energy of the system.

> 3. How does one obtain entropy from the work-energy

If by "work-energy" you mean the work-energy theorem, that theorem is not directly connected to entropy. That theorem, when correctly stated, is

*The net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.*

Your first equation omits the critical distinction between work, and net work. It should read: $\Delta K=W_{net}$.

That being said, friction work does generate entropy because friction work is irreversible. Heat transfer across a finite temperature difference also generates entropy because it is also irreversible.

**__________________________________________________________**

Now, regarding the series of introductory equations and statements that were made, I have the following comments and questions..

> The work-energy theory states:
>
> > $\Delta$ K = W

This is incomplete. It should read:

$$\Delta K=W_{net}$$

The work energy theorem states that the *net* work done on an object equals the change in its kinetic energy. The word "net" cannot be overemphasized. Because if one raises an object from rest on the ground and places it at rest a height $h$ above the ground, one does positive work of $mgh$ but there is no change in kinetic energy. That's because gravity does an equal amount of negative work $-mgh$ for a net work of zero. Gravity takes away the energy one puts into the object and stores it as gravitational potential energy of the earth-object system.

> John Taylor breaks work into conservative and non-conservative work:
>
> > $\Delta K = W_c + W_{nc} $

Be careful now. As I indicated, $\Delta K$ in the first equation is equal to the *net* work done on an object, not just work in general. You haven't given the context of John Taylor's statement, but I believe he is probably talking about work in general and not the net work associated with the work energy theorem. Are you sure Taylor uses $\Delta K$ on the left side of the equation and that it is not written as follows?:

$$W=W_{c}+W_{nc}$$

I'm concerned you are now attempting to construct a logical set of equations under the wrong assumption of what $W$ is in the first equation.

> One type of non-conservative work is friction, which i beak up into
>   friction work and other non-conservative work
>
> > $\Delta K = W_c + (W_{frict} + W_{nco}) $

Again, along the lines of what I have already said, this equation should probably read:

$$W = W_c + (W_{frict} + W_{nco}) $$

> According to the [Wikipedia article on friction][1]:
>
> $E_{th} = W_{frict} $

IMO the Wikipedia article is poorly written in this regard. They are saying that friction work equals heat. That is not correct. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Friction is energy transfer by means of work. Although the term "friction heating" is commonly used (and because of that I'm often compelled to use it myself), friction is not a "heating process". The work involved in the relative motion between the surfaces results in an increase in the internal energy of the surfaces as reflected by an increase in their temperatures. Then heat transfers from the higher temperature surfaces to the interior of the materials and the environment.

> Hence,
>
> $\Delta K = W_c + (-E_{th} + W_{nco}) $
>
> where the minus sign is due to the system doing the work on the
>   surroundings.

Again, replace $\Delta K$ with $W$. Regarding the sign, and the statement "due to the system doing work on the surroundings", nowhere in your presentation do you define the system and the surroundings.

> The potential energy is also found as:
>
> $\Delta K = - \Delta U + (-E_{th} + W_{nco}) $

In thermodynamics, $U$ is generally used for internal energy for a closed system. Apparently you are using it for the potential energy of the system. Putting it on the left side of the equation gives the total change in mechanical energy of the system. The right side should then be the external work done on the system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it does! Thank you so much! Navigating thermodynamics is like stepping on hot coals!